# Assigning an inverse function at definition time

Tags: j

I've written a little toy hexadecimal converter; I have an encode and a decode function:

```
encode16 =: { & '0123456789ABCDEF' @ ((6 $ 16) & #:)
decode16 =: (16 & #.) @ ('0123456789ABCDEF' & i.)
```

I would like them to be inverses of each other, so I can write code and see something like this:

```
   119&+ &. decode16 '03A8D8'
03A94F
```

My first guess was to add this:

```
encode16 =: encode16 :. decode16
```

This creates recursion, so I settled on this instead:

```
encode16basic =: { & '0123456789ABCDEF' @ ((6 $ 16) & #:)
decode16basic =: (16 & #.) @ ('0123456789ABCDEF' & i.)

encode16 =: encode16basic :. decode16basic
decode16 =: decode16basic :. encode16basic
```

Is this the typical way to handle inverse functions? Do people typically assign inverse functions at definition time? And is it really necessary to assign the inverse to both the encode and decode functions? It seems like it is, since the documentation doesn't say otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option for defining them might be:

```
   encode16=: ({&'0123456789ABCDEF'@((6$16)&#:)) :. ((16&#.)@('0123456789ABCDEF'&i.))
   decode16=: encode16^:_1

   119&+&.decode16 '03A8D8'
03A94F
```

You can inspect the obverse of a verb as follows:

```
   decode16 b. _1
encode16
   encode16 b. _1
16&#.@('0123456789ABCDEF'&i.) :.({&'0123456789ABCDEF'@(16 16 16 16 16 16&#:))
```

Check out the [wiki page for Obverse](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/codot) for more detail.

Comment: Surprisingly, it looks like explicitly coding the inverse isn't even necessary.